# Is it possible to copy public key of a local instance to ec2-instance authorised key section, while ec2-instance spuns up, using playbook

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, public-key, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I need to spin up an ec2-instance from local machine and copy the public key of local machine to ec2-instance while the ec2-instance spuns up.

Edit

As suggested in the comments I have tried to use the [`authorized_keys` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html)

```
- name: Deploy SSH Key
  authorized_key:
    user: ec2-user
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    path: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: "msg": "Failed to lookup user ec2-user: 'getpwnam(): name not found: ec2-user'"}
```

Edit:
@anyone, My ansible playbook spuns up ec2-instance and i need to copy the public key to this instance, the default user is ec2-user, so what will I do to resolve this.
The authorized_keys module copies ssh keys from local instance and pastes in the 
home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys, location of local instance itself.
it doesn't copy the public key to the newly created instance.

Comment: Did you try with the [`authorized_key` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html)?

Comment: Please do not put follow-ups/ additional info in comments, edit your question, I did it for you this time but think about in the future. Your error seems to indicate that the `ec2-user` does not exist on your target server.